# Evaluate complex integral $\int_{\gamma} (z^3 +z^2 -2) dz$ where $\gamma(t)=[-1,1,i,-1]$ is the closed triangular.

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral $\int_{\gamma} (z^3 +z^2 -2) dz$ where $\gamma(t)=[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_1]$ is the closed polygonal path with $z_1=-1,z_2=1, z_3=i$.

My textbook has a theorem that says this: If $A$ is simply connected region and $f(z)$ is analytic on $A$, and $C$ is a simple closed curve in $A$ then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$.

Now my question is: can I apply the theorem above to this integral and conclude $\int_{\gamma}( z^3 +z^2 -2) dz =0$?

I think the answer is yes because  $z^3 +z^2 -2 $ is analytic on the entire complex plane. I am, unsure, however if $\gamma(t)=[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_1]$ is considered a simple closed curve.

Comment: Depends on the purpose of the exercise, but yes the integral is $0.$ If the exercise comes before the theorem, the purpose of the exercise might be to (1) Let you learn how to compute such integrals, and (2) see an example before you learn the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  By Cauchy's theorem the integral is zero.   The curve can have sharp points. Any *regular* closed curve will do.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept best answer when it enables me to